# Simulink Coder Error : Unable to find build success text "### Successfully generated all binary outputs." in build log

Tags: simulink

I am trying to generate code for a sample model which implements concurrent execution. It is an example given by [Mathworks](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/implement-data-parallelism-in-simulink.html). When trying to build the model through the "Profiler Report" in concurrent execution window or by using "rtwbuild(mdl)", I am getting the same error,

```
C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/win64/createResponseFile.exe 1  data_parallel_model.rsp data_parallel_model.obj data_parallel_model_data.obj
"### Creating standalone executable "../data_parallel_model.exe" ..."
"C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2017b/sys/lcc64/lcc64/bin/lcclnk64" -s -LC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2017b/sys/lcc64/lcc64/lib64  -o ../data_parallel_model.exe @data_parallel_model.rsp rt_main.obj @data_parallel_model_ref.rsp  
rt_main.obj .text: undefined reference to '_InterlockedIncrement'
gmake: *** [../data_parallel_model.exe] Error 1
### Unable to find build success text: "### Successfully generated all binary outputs." in build log.
Error in coder.make.Builder/coder_build
Error in coder.make.Builder/run
Error in coder.make.invokeBuilder
Error in RTW/genMakefileAndBuild
Error in RTW/genMakefileAndBuildWrapper
Error in coder.internal.compileStage
Error in coder.internal.ModelBuilder/buildProcedure (line 1107)
                compileResult = coder.internal.compileStage...
Error in coder.internal.ModelBuilder/make_rtw (line 197)
                buildResult = buildProcedure...
Error in coder.internal.ModelCodegenMgr/make_rtw (line 8)
    buildResult = obj.make_rtw(varargin);
Error in make_rtw (line 20)
buildResult = h.make_rtw(buildArgs, varargin{:});
Error in build_target
Error in build_target
Error in build_standalone_rtw_target
Error in slbuild_private
Error in slbuild_private
Error in sl (line 15)
[varargout{1:nargout}]=feval(varargin{:});
Error in slbuild (line 72)
    sl('slbuild_private', mdl, target, varargin{2:end});
Error in rtwbuild (line 217)
              slbuild(sys, 'StandaloneRTWTarget', ...
```

I tried searching but I couldn't find any solutions on the internet. I found one similar question in this Forum here but there is no solution.

What is the reason for this error?

MATLAB : 2017b

Coder: Embedded Coder

Answer (score 0):

Your build failed for some reason. See the previous message in your log "undefined reference to '_InterlockedIncrement'". This is reported by lcc linker. Are you using calling some external code for which you have not specified source or library? That would be reason for this kind of linker error.

The message unable to find "build success text", is just pointing out that building the generated source code failed for some reason.

Comment: Yes I observed this error "undefined reference to '_InterlockedIncrement". I don't think there is any external code. It is an example from Mathworks as attached in the question. The model consists only constant, gain and discrete time Integrator blocks. However, I tried to build the model without the concurrent execution, it was built successfully. Do you have any idea why turning on "Allow Tasks to execute concurrently on target" might arise this error?